# Including angular templates on one external .html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive

In angular, you can create a template in the page itself like:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="something.htm">
    <div>This is a template.</div>
</script>
```

I'm wondering if you can take a bunch of these and put them together in an external page, like "templates.htm", and then reference the entire page, essentially saying "look in templates.htm for the template something.htm."

Comment: I could just load it in with jQuery, but I'm hoping there's something in the angular pipeline or something somewhere.

Comment: You could request the raw html of external.html and compile with the `$compile` service, it will put those template into the `$templateCache` for you.

Comment: Like: $compile(returnedData)($rootScope);?

Comment: Would that be available across isolate scope borders?

Comment: Yes, but note that it will only work with directives that get compiled after the above statement.

Comment: So if you did it in a directive's link function, the template wouldn't be available to that directive because the directive has already been compiled.

Comment: BTW, why exactly you would want to do this? There may be another solution that serve your needs.

Comment: I have lots of templates big enough that template: '...' would be awkward, but small enough that separate files seems unnecessary. I want to combine them all into templates.htm.

Comment: You want to combine them just to boost a performance right? I mean a single http request to get them all.

Comment: Yes. And also to keep my file system clean.

Comment: I $compile'd the results of an $http get against $rootScope, which seemed to work at first, but after a few refreshes, it quit working because the get didn't return before the template was requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind a little decrease in performance, here is a working example for what I have said in the comment.

**Example:** http://plnkr.co/edit/EcEySnmmm3hsLimDHfYr?p=preview

The key concept is to remove the `np-app` and bootstrap the app manually after the `templates.html` is loaded.

```
$.get('templates.html').done(function (rawHtml) {
  angular.module('app').run(function ($compile) {
    $compile(rawHtml)({});
  });

  angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
  });
});
```

Comment: Right. Manual bootstrapping. Can't believe I forgot about that. Thanks runTarm!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this as simple as using an ng-include ?

```
      <ng-include  src="'mytemplates.html'"></ng-include>
```

(mind the single quotes with src)

@Aaron: Adding more information on what i did.
Here is the body of my index.html ( the main page)

```
      <body ng-app="">
        <ng-include src="'mytemplates.html'"></ng-include>
        <p><a ng-click="currentTpl='/tpl.html'" id="tpl-link">Load external template                    1</a>
        </p>
        <p><a ng-click="currentTpl='/tp2.html'" id="tpl-link">Load external template 2</a>
        </p>
        <p><a ng-click="currentTpl='/tp3.html'" id="tpl-link">Load external template                 3</a>
         </p>
         Content:
        <div id="tpl-content" ng-include src="currentTpl"></div>
        </body>
```

And here is the mytemplates.html

```
           <script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
                Content of the template 1
           </script>
           <script type="text/ng-template" id="/tp2.html">
                Content of the template 2.
           </script>

           <script type="text/ng-template" id="/tp3.html">
                Content of the template 3.
           </script>
```

When i click the links i can see that the templates do get loaded. Am i missing something ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The same $digest that processes the ng-include processes the directives that need the templates in mytemplates.html. It'll 404 looking for the template files since the ng-templates aren't loaded yet.

Comment: @AaronF: added more script on what i did.. But reading your comment again, i think i need to do a bit more thinking.. :)

Comment: Here's an example of what I'm trying to do: http://plnkr.co/edit/KMU2mIGpAlZJCnNXfnFZ?p=preview (using your ng-include proposal.)

Comment: @AaronF: i don't see any files in the plnkr link..is it the right link?

Comment: It was private. Here's a public fork: http://plnkr.co/edit/b0mUzpS8FdsWt6z72lYa?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

While technically not a direct answer to your question, a very clean solution and probably best performance wise would be to use [html2js](https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js).

It will take the .html templates you give it and turn them into one or more .js files containing code that fills the template cache. Then you just include the generated .js file and you're done. The client should not request the .html files - it will check the cache first.

It does require some changes to your build setup but can be fully automated.

Comment: Yeah, I would encorage the use of html2js as well, but it's just violate the OP's `keep my file system clean` rule :p

Comment: is one .js file such a big deal? or is it the multiple small .html files - i say keep your templates close to your code, so placing all the small templates in a single location goes against my experience, it's better to tackle that as part of your build process, but thats just me

Comment: I couldn't agree more as I always do the same thing. The only problem I could see is that for someone that is not familiar a build system will take some times to get it works.

Comment: I might use it, except that our entire system is ASP.NET. It's years too late to use node. And also, I want all the templates in one file.

Comment: hmm i can certainly understand that too, i hope you won't mind if i keep this answer here - someone else might find it useful