# Cache combined AngularJS templates for a module?

Tags: angularjs

I want to pre-load all of my AngularJS templates required by a module. I can't find any way of doing this when the templates have already been combined into a single file.

For example, I have a single html file called "templates.html" with the following structure:

```
<script type='text/ng-template' id='directive1.html'>
    <p>Directive One</p>
</script>

<script type='text/ng-template' id='directive2.html'>
    <p>Directive Two</p>
</script>
```

My directives have their templateUrls set appropriately to `directive1.html` and `directive2.html`.

What I'd like to do is have the module load the `templates.html` file at start-up and cache all of the templates.

I've found examples for this, but only when the directive templates are in individual files, not when they are already combined.

Ideally there would be a `$templateCache.load("/templates.html")` method, but I haven't found such a thing.

Comment: This answer may helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24809643/867480

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use this great grunt task: [grunt-angular-templates](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates).
I'm using it.

It would do the whole task of caching all templates you indicate for you.

Therefore, your `directive1.html` and `directive2.html` will be cached.

Comment: There is also gulp angular templatecache: https://github.com/miickel/gulp-angular-templatecache

Comment: I'm using .NET for this and I'd rather not add another build process into the mix. I'm mostly perplexed as to why this doesn't already exist in Angular.